# Different values of the same variable at Watch Table and at Data Tip

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, watch

I have pretty odd issue while watching a variable at the same moment at Watch Table and at Data Tip. The same variable looks differently at both places at the same time.

I'm using VS2015. How is that possible? Both values must be same?